# WCF Service accessing UNC path of Sharepoint document library

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, aspose

I have a WCF service which is accessing Sharepoint document library UNC path, Picking word file and converting to pdf using aspose.words and dropping the converted file to another document library using UNC path.

It's working fine when I run the service using VS WCF Test client and not working when I published the service to IIS. Appreciate your help.

Here is the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Access Denied. 

Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)\r\n     
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)\r\n       
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)\r\n   at Aspose.Words.Document..ctor(String fileName, LoadOptions loadOptions)\r\n   at Word2PdfSvc.Convert2Pdf.SavePdf(String sourceUrl, String srcFileName, String destinationUrl, String dstFileName)"
```